# xception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1703, Size: 1699 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)

Tags: java, arraylist

```
//arraylist problem
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double Vn=0;
   double thetap=0;
   List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int c = 0; c < 2000; c++){
      ints.add(c);
   }
   while(ints.size()!=0) { 
      int x=rnd.nextInt();
      if(x>=0&&x<2000) {
         if(ints.contains(x)){
            double r=10;
            double Vc= r * r / 3.0D;//area
            Vn+=Vc;   //sum         
            ints.remove(x);// that's the problem
            thetap=Vn/V;

         }
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

For `int`, `contains` looks up the value, while [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) remove the element at the index.

So after a number of deletions, the number near the end might have a smaller index, e.g.,

```
0, 1, 2 -> 0, 2
```

So here `contains(2)` will be true, but `remove(2)` gives you an exception.

Also, `remove` does have a [variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) that removes the first occurrence of the object.

Comment: +1  Yes, remove() is confusing for autoboxed types.  Did something like this ever make it into Java Puzzlers?

Comment: The problem is not really that. He is already checking for `x` between the range of indices. Only problem is he is testing against wrong range.

Comment: @RohitJain: but he also checks `contains()`

Comment: @jlordo. Yeah, that's some logical problem that OP needs to sort out. That is not related to the current issue.

Comment: @RohitJain Perhaps, but you "fix" breaks the code, while jlordo's does not.

Comment: x is the value that i want to remove. to my understanding, do you mean that i did not remove x but the index of x?

Comment: @sophiaxiong I think you are right - you are not removing `x`, you are removing the element at index `x`, which is out of bound.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [`remove(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29), not [`remove(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29). Try

```
ints.remove(Integer.valueOf(x));
```

Comment: Well, this will resolve the current issue as well. Probably it's better way. Removing my answer.

Comment: what i mean to do is to remove x, x is the number that i want to remove from the array, so that the next time i produce a random number which should be contained in the array(x has been excluded). I am not sure if i should remove both the value and the index at the same time.

Comment: @sophiaxiong: in your code you should delete `ints.remove(x);` and replace it with the code in my answer.